# Office 365: Using PowerShell to outout a list of OneDrives and thier consumed space

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business

Can the community advise if it's possible to output a list of active One Drive for Business Sites within an Office tenancy alongside the amount of storage that it's consuming?

As an administrator, using the GUI, I'd have to log in via the User Profiles and check manually, which for an enterprise, clearly isn't viable.

I've seen the following link that advised how to get a list of sites but am unsure as to whether this can be edited to also include storage space that's being consumed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn911464.aspx

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to on-prem SharePoint, but may translate:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_-_inside_the_lines/2015/09/08/get-site-collection-size-with-powershell/

Perhaps in the if($Url) block:

```
if ($Url) {
$site = Get-SPOSite $Url
$sizeInKb = $site.Usage.Storage
$Url $sizeInKb | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
}
```